# Node Express API file upload returns 404 only on production

Tags: node.js, express, http, file-upload, multer

File upload method works on localhost, but in production a POST request returns "Cannot GET /establishments/1/image".

**This is my router**

```
routes.post(
  '/establishments/:establishmentId/image',
  multer(multerConfig).single('file'),
  EstablishmentImageController.store
);
```

**This is the controller**

```
class EstablishmentImageController {
  async store(req, res) {
    const { establishmentId } = req.params;
    const establishment = await Establishment.findByPk(establishmentId);
    if (establishment === null)
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Not found.' });
    if (establishment.image_url !== null)
      return res
        .status(403)
        .json({ error: 'This establishment already have an image.' });
    await Establishment.update(
      { image_url: req.file.filename },
      { where: { id: establishmentId } }
    );
    establishment.image_url = req.file.filename;
    return res.status(200).json(establishment);
  }
}
```

**This is multer configuration**

```
import multer from 'multer';
import path from 'path';
import crypto from 'crypto';

export default {
  dest: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'tmp', 'uploads'),
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'tmp', 'uploads'));
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) cb(err);
        const fileName = `${hash.toString('hex')}-${file.originalname}`;
        cb(null, fileName);
      });
    },
  }),
  limits: {
    fileSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024,
  },
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    const allowedMimes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png'];
    if (allowedMimes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(new Error('Invalid file type.'));
    }
  },
};
```

I've tried to renamed tmp folder to other things, tried to change its place, renamed the route... Nothing workd. What's most strange is that is seems to not even recognize the route, as it's a POST request but the return says 'Cannot GET'. **PS: It's working on localhost**.

Comment: Well, it's pretty weird that it says `"Cannot GET"` when you're supposed to be doing a `POST`.  `"Cannot GET"` means it's trying to do a `GET`, not a `POST` which would not match your route handler.  Please show the client code that is supposed to be doing the POST.

Comment: Is you router responding to a port number?  If that is the issue you will need to post proxy config in your package.json file.

Comment: @jfriend00, I'm using Postman! I would like to reinforce that it's working on localhost.